# What do Paz and Zurek mean by "one-bit" measurement in Heiss' Fundamentals of Quantum Information?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, decoherence

In Heiss' Fundamentals of Quantum Information (2002, p. 90) Paz and Zurek look at a "One-Bit Environment for a Bit-by-Bit Measurement". At the end they say, that decoherence because of "one-bit" measurements has been observed in experiment. What do they mean by that exactly?

My way of understanding this is, that this refers to the amount of qubits that the environment (next to the system and the apparatus) consists from.

Comment: This  [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0105127) by Zurek talks about the same thing and is much easier to access. Without further details from you it is hard to figure out what *they* mean by that excactly. What experiment?

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't seem to provide more information rather than putting the whole article in here (or at least some pages of it). Thank you for the suggestion!